How to increase the font size of CJK text specifically while using luatex-ja?
I need to increase the font size of the CJK text specifically (not the ruby text above it though), and not change the font size of the English text. Any leads on how to make it work?
here's a minimal working example of the code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\def\ltj@stdmcfont{file:kaiu.ttf}
\makeatother

\usepackage{luatexja}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\usepackage{luatexja-ruby}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\rubysize}{0.7}
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{\dimexpr0.25ex-0.5\baselineskip\relax}
\setstretch{1.5}

\begin{document}
    \ruby{自}{ㄗ4} \ruby{禁}{ㄐㄧㄣ4} \ruby{者}{ㄓㄜ3} \ruby{以}{ㄧ3} \ruby{德}{ㄉㄜ2} \ruby{導}{ㄉㄠ3} \ruby{欲}{ㄩ4} : The person who restrains themselves leads their desires with virtue. 
\end{document}


You can use the luatexja-fontspec commands (from section 3.2 of the luatexja  manual) to load your Japanese fonts, and give them the Scale= option from fontspec.  There is also a scale= package option for luatexja-fontspec.
To specify font commands for Ruby characters, you can use the fontcmd= setting of luatexja-ruby.  You can set this with \ltjsetruby.  The command you want might be (from the manual)
\ltjsetruby{fontcmd=\addjfontfeatures{Style=Ruby}}

Here is an example that selects a Ruby font family and switches to it:
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3 % Make missing characters an error!
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{luatexja}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\usepackage{luatexja-ruby}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\setmainjfont{HaranoAjiMincho}[
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  BoldFont=*-Bold]
  
\setsansjfont{HaranoAjiGothic}[
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
  UprightFont=*-Medium,
  BoldFont=*-Bold]

\newjfontfamily\rubyfont{NotoSerifCJKjp}[
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
  Style=Ruby,
  UprightFont=*-Semibold,
  BoldFont=*-Black,
  Extension=.otf]

\ltjsetruby{fontcmd=\rubyfont}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand*{\rubysize}{0.7}
\newcommand*{\rubysep}{\dimexpr0.25ex-0.5\baselineskip\relax}
\setstretch{1.5}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \ruby{自}{ㄗ4} \ruby{禁}{ㄐㄧㄣ4} \ruby{者}{ㄓㄜ3} \ruby{以}{ㄧ3} \ruby{德}{ㄉㄜ2} \ruby{導}{ㄉㄠ3} \ruby{欲}{ㄩ4} :\\
    The person who restrains themselves leads their desires with virtue. 
\end{document}


